# sed -i command issue with '

Tags: sed, files

I am trying to edit a line in a large text file using the sed command in linux.

The original line from my file.txt is:

```
Cg64_2043 XI1.MM1.GATE vss '0.0'
```

I essentially want to change the 0.0 in the line to 10. The issue is there is a ' in the line itself which seems to send the sed command. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

```
sed -i '/Cg64_2043 XI1.MM1.GATE vss '0.0'/s/0.0/10/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use double quotes instead.

```
sed -i "/Cg64_2043 XI1\.MM1\.GATE vss '0\.0'/s/0\.0/10/" file.txt
```

And there's no point in first checking for the match and then replacing, just replace. It won't do anything it doesn't match:

```
sed -i "s/\(Cg64_2043 XI1\.MM1\.GATE vss \)'0\.0'/\1'10'/" file.txt
```

Or, if your sed supports `-E` (most do):

```
sed -E -i "s/(Cg64_2043 XI1\.MM1\.GATE vss )'0\.0'/\1'10'/" file.txt
```